# Only getting "draw" result in Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Javascript, and for some reason, no matter what the player input is, I always get a "draw" result.  I've been trying to figure it out for the last hour but no dice.  Any help is really appreciated.  I've put my code below.

````
         let computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }

        let playerPrompt = prompt("Rock, paper, or scissors?")
        let playerChoice = String(playerPrompt).toLowerCase

         function playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice) {
            if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
                return "Draw!"
            } else if (playerChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "scissors") {
                return "Player wins!"
            } else if (playerChoice === "paper" && computerChoice === "rock") {
                return "Player wins!"
            } else if (playerChoice === "scissors" && computerChoice === "paper") {
                return "Player wins!"
            } else {
                return "Computer wins!"
            }
        }

        let results = playRound()
        console.log(results)```
````

Comment: You don't pass the parameters to the function!

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. Use `console.log` to find out what `playerChoice` and `computerChoice` actually are. You forgot to pass them to `playRound` when you called it, and you set `playerChoice` to be the `toLowerCase` **function** instead of calling that function and getting the return value. Your problems are basically a collection of typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're not passing any arguments to `playRound()`, it should probably be:

```
let results = playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice)
```

Edit: As mentionned by Quentin (and Alon Eitan) it is not the only problem:

```
let playerChoice = String(playerPrompt).toLowerCase
```

actually assigns the function `String.toLowerCase` to `playerChoice`, if you want the lower case value of `playerPrompt` the syntax should be

```
let playerChoice = playerPrompt.toLowerCase()
```

or directly

```
let playerChoice = prompt("Rock, paper, or scissors?").toLowerCase()
```

Comment: It will try to compare a string to a function with the current code, so it's not the only problem - See Quentin's comment

Comment: I read it right after posting, my answer was hasty indeed :) I haven't found how to delete it, however

Comment: You can [edit] your answer instead, I don't think that you need to delete it

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you! I figured it would be something really obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The error is toLowerCase instead of toLowerCase(), you missed the parenthesis. Try running this snippet, it works

```js
let computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }

        let playerPrompt = prompt("Rock, paper, or scissors?")
        let playerChoice = String(playerPrompt).toLowerCase()

         function playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice) {
 
            if (playerChoice === computerChoice) {
                return "Draw!"
            } else if (playerChoice === "rock" && computerChoice === "scissors") {
                return "Player wins!"
            } else if (playerChoice === "paper" && computerChoice === "rock") {
                return "Player wins!"
            } else if (playerChoice === "scissors" && computerChoice === "paper") {
                return "Player wins!"
            } else {
                return "Computer wins!"
            }
        }

        let results = playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice)
        console.log(results)
```

Comment: Try to explain what you did to solve the problem, your modification is drown in the code that's unchanged.

Comment: toLowerCase() instead of toLowerCase